# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientTop' of undefined - CKEDITOR 4.112

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

A. Provide detailed reproduction steps (if any)
1. Write some text
2. Select all and set align center/right/justified

B. Expected result
Back focus at end of text

C. Actual result
When set cursor at end or else of the text, cursor back again to first line and can't set the focus. except we set first line align to left, the editor will normal again

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientTop' of undefined
    at window.CKEDITOR.window.CKEDITOR.dom.CKEDITOR.dom.element.getDocumentPosition (ckeditor.js:114)
    at z (ckeditor.js:1018)
    at y (ckeditor.js:1020)
    at window.CKEDITOR.window.CKEDITOR.dom.CKEDITOR.dom.element.mouseNear (ckeditor.js:1007)
    at ckeditor.js:1025`

ckeditor issues here https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/issues/3635

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem because i set interval to get onChange value from ckeditor, this is wrong way. ckeditor has own onChange handler